# Создать ссылку на определенное место в документе excel

Tags: python, excel

Имеется excel-файл с большим количеством листов, на каждом из которых есть таблица (датафрейм). На одном из них располагается информация о связи названия таблицы и листа (оглавление).

```
{1: 'Собаки',
 2: 'Кошки',
 3: 'Птицы',
 4: 'Насекомые',
 5: 'Рыбы'}
```

То есть на листе под названием "1" находится таблица с данными про собак и тд.

Можно ли как-то средствами python создать такой инструмент, с помощью которого нажав на название листа я автоматически перейду на этот лист (насколько я знаю в самом excel это можно сделать, но хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `openpyxl`:

- Создал документ
- Создал второй лист
- На первом листе добавил в ячейку гиперссылку на второй лист и ячейку `K20`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7d755344430cdcf44d38cf4c7a8420b7e06ecd10/office__excel__openpyxl__xlwt/xlsx__hyperlink_cell_to_sheet.py#L16)

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.active

sheet2 = wb.create_sheet(title='Лист 2')

cell = sheet1.cell(row=1, column=1)
cell.hyperlink = f"#'{sheet2.title}'!K20"
cell.value = "Go"

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
```

Для уже существующего файла:

```
import openpyxl


filename = 'excel.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename)

sheet1 = wb['Sheet']
sheet2 = wb['Лист 2']

cell = sheet1.cell(row=5, column=1)
cell.hyperlink = f"#'{sheet2.title}'!B20"
cell.value = "Go2"

wb.save(filename)
```

**UPD.**
Еще можно создавать ссылки через класс `Hyperlink`:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink import Hyperlink
...

cell = sheet1.cell(row=2, column=1)
cell.hyperlink = Hyperlink(
    location=f"'{sheet2.title}'!K20",
    ref='',
)
cell.value = "Go 2"
cell.style = "Hyperlink"
```

Comment: а можно ли тоже самое сделать с уже существующим файлом?

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, добавил пример

Comment: играет ли роль приложение, в котором открывается файл? я работаю на mac в numbers, и ссылка не создается

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, не знаю, мб. А если с нуля создать файл экселя, то тоже не работает? На маке вроде бы есть Excel... Попробуйте на нем проверить - я на нем проверял :) А в numbers ссылки на ячейки других листов нормально создаются?

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, визуально, оно, кст, выглядит как обычный текст - там нет синего текста и подчеркивания (наверное, нужно стиль текста указывать), но текст кликабельный. У вас текст кликабельный?

Comment: если создавать ссылку в самом приложении numbers, то она кликабельная, подчеркнута и выделена синим цветом и все работает. если с помощью кода, то ссылка просто не создается.

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, и при клике на ссылку, созданную из кода, ничего не происходит?

Comment: ничего, остается все как обычный текст. возможно это проблема самого приложения. в приложении excel работает

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, а попробуйте ссылку создать через класс. Добавил в ответе пример

Comment: теперь все работает. Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, пожалуйста :)